# Error deploying Azure Machine Learning Studio Designer inference pipeline: "ImportError with werkzeug.urls" in real-time endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-container-instances, azure-ai

I am using one of the pre-built pipelines in Azure Machine Learning Studio designer, specifically the 'Wide & Deep based Recommendation - Restaurant Rating Prediction' pipeline. I have successfully run the pipeline to train the model and create an inference pipeline. However, I encountered an error when attempting to deploy the model to the real-time endpoint. The error message I'm receiving is:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'url_quote' from 'werkzeug.urls'
```

This error occurs when deploying to both AKS (AksCompute) and ACI (Azure Container Instances) compute types.

I suspect that downgrading the version of Werkzeug to 2.2.2 may resolve the issue, but I am unsure how to do this in the Azure Machine Learning Studio environment.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom environment to add extra dependencies and packages, and select that environment while deploying the endpoint.

Follow the steps below to create a custom environment:

1. Go to **Environments** > **Custom environments** > **Create**

   [image]
2. Next, give a name to the environment.

   [image]
3. I selected the existing environment for the **Select environment source** option. If you have a Docker context, you can choose that as well.
4. Next, I selected **model-evaluation** for the environment type. You can select according to your requirements.

   [image]
5. Click on next, and you will see the customization options as shown below.

   [image]
6. Here, you will find a `conda.yaml` or `requirements.txt` file. Click on it and add your package names.

   [image]
7. After creating the environment, register the model and start deploying it in a real-time endpoint.

   To register, refer to the image below:

   [image]

   To deploy:

   [image]
8. While deploying the model, select the created custom environment in the **Code + environment** tab.

   [image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question, your solution is working!